# Common root between quadratic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, quadratics, common-root

Let $a,b \in N $ and $a \neq b$

If $(a-1)x^2-(a^2+2)x+a^2+2a=0$

and

$(b-1)x^2-(b^2+2)x+b^2+2b=0$

have a common root then the value of $ab$ is ?

I tried using Cramer's rule for common root but that did not simplify to anything and on subtracting the equations I again ended up with a quadratic, on solving the quadratic I got

$$x=\frac{a^2-b^2\pm\sqrt{(b^2-a^2)^2-4(a-b)(a^2-b^2+2a-2b)}}{2(a-b)}$$
which does not simplify either.

Any hints on how should I solve this.

Comment: You are able to isolate $(a-b)^2$ inside the radical by grouping

Comment: Please type out your expression rather than posting a picture.

Comment: Did the accepted post below allow you to reach an answer to the question in your post?

Comment: Yes, why do you ask ?

Comment: Because I fail to see how, naturally. Care to explain? (Unrelated: please use @.)

Comment: @Did since there is a common root I took 2 roots at a time and equated them only $x_3=x_2 and x_1=x_4$ give answers

Comment: Did you note another post provides your answer without all these loops and cases?

Comment: @Did I did, but I haven't studied the concept used there.

Comment: Yeah. You do not say the context you were asked this in but if I were you, I would readily forget the "answer" you saw fit to accept and instead, give a look or two at the link in Robert's answer. Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solving the two quadratic equations we get
$$x_1=\frac{a+2}{a-1},x_2=a$$
$$x_3=\frac{b+2}{b-1},x_4=b$$
if we have $$x_1=x_3$$ we have $$(a+2)(b-1)=(b+2)(a-1)$$ solving this we obtain $a=b$
can you solve the other cases?

Comment: But how would I know which 2 are equal

Comment: hm you must calculate all possibilities

Comment: $x_3=x_2$ and $x_1=x_4$ both give answers so which one should I accept

Comment: which answers do you got?

Comment: a = 4 or 2 and b = 2 or 4

Comment: yes and $ab=4\cdot 2=8$

Comment: But since there is only one common root only one of them can be equal at a time

Comment: but you have two Parameters $a,b$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are the left sides of your two equations, the [resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is $3(ab-a-b-2)^2(a-b)^2$.  This is $0$ if and only if the equations have a common root.  Thus $$ab = a + b + 2$$
Write this as $$(a-1)(b-1) = 3$$  S
Since $3$ is prime, if $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers we need $a-1$ and $b-1$ to be 
$1$ and $3$ (in either order).  Thus one of $a$ and $b$ is $2$ and the other is $4$.

Comment: What do you mean by resultant ?

Comment: Link added.....